# Replace multiple documents with one approve

Tags: server, 2019

Sharepoint Server 2019.
When i drag and drop some files to sharepoint with same name, sharepoint ask what i want to do with files that have same name.
I need replace files. But sharepoint ask me for each file.
Is it possible to upload files by answering this question only once and for this to apply to all documents?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve that by mapping SharePoint library as a network drive or just by opening the explorer view (there is command in the library ribbon).